# Usage of Rabbis Tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags

The [rabbis tag](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/195) says that it is intended for "Questions about the lives and personalities of Jewish religious authorities."

I agree that there is reason for a rabbis tag.

However, this description pretty much limits questions about rabbis, to those which are off-topic according the FAQs of the site [which limits questions to those about Judaism not Jews](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Accordingly, I am soliciting suggestions for a tag edit.

Comment: Commentless downvoter?

Answer (score 2):

For [hebrew](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew), we have excerpt:

> Questions pertaining to the Hebrew language, as related to Judaism. See the help center: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

And body:

> About the Hebrew language.
>
> Note that not all questions about Hebrew are on-topic on the site. See [the FAQ list](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq). For a dedicated Stack Exchange site about the Hebrew language, come support the [Hebrew Language Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75348/hebrew-language/).
>
> If you're looking for a tag about the Hebrews — the nation of Jews — as a whole, try instead [am-yisrael-jewish-nation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/am-yisrael-jewish-nation).

Following the same pattern for [rabbis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rabbis), I suggest excerpt:

> Questions about the lives and personalities of Jewish religious authorities, as related to Judaism. See the help center: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

And body:

> About the the lives and personalities of Jewish religious authorities, as related to Judaism.
>
> Note that not all questions about individual rabbis are on-topic on the site. See [the FAQ list](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Consider as well adding a parallel to http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2219/759

Comment: I prefer mine as it is essentially the distilled version of yours, IMO. I am of course biased.

Comment: That is to say, this is somewhat misleading, as questions about the lives an personalities of rabbis are almost never on topic. Saying that they are on topic as related to Judaism is somewhat tautological. Kind of like saying that cholesterol is healthy when part of a healthy lifestyle including a proper diet and exercise...

Comment: @mevaqesh, that's incorrect. That a question contains a biographical or historical component [does not](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=15350294#15350294) make it off-topic any more than asking about a [tag:hebrew] word, or, for that matter, [tag:gentiles] do. I agree that from a formal logic point of view, no tag description needs to include "as related to Judaism," but for topics that people might think make a question on-topic in and of themselves [but don't](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1474/2), I think the tag writeup is a good place to put a helpful reminder.

Comment: ... If the intent of your formulation is to rule out questions that contain a biographical aspect, then that is contrary to how [the relevant site policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1474/2) and on-topicness in general are meant to work. Generally speakin, the presence of a particular topic in a question does not make it off-topic; the absence of one particular subject - Judaism - in a question makes it off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

> Questions relating to the roles of rabbis in Jewish law, life, and thought.